# Allow Objects Created on a Background Thread to be Accessed on the UI Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a program that has a WPF UI and gathers and formats a bunch of data from a server.  I want the user to be able to press a button to start data collection and not have the UI freeze up while that runs.  When the data collection is done, I want all the data collected to be dumped to the UI to be displayed.

I'm very new to c#, multithreading, and MVVM so feel free to correct any mistakes I make.

Originally I started using `BackgroundWorker`.  After a bunch of reading, I came across multiple people saying that `BackgroundWorker` is older and that `async` and `await` should be used.  I have done a bunch of looking on this website as well as looking through the official MS documentation and examples but haven't found a good example that accomplishes what I need with the data structure I have.

My data structure is a list of custom class objects with multiple properties. 
 Each object can hold more child objects of the same type.  This forms a hierarchy.  The way I'm using it is the top-level list actually only has one "root" element in it and then the rest of the elements are children under this.  The hierarchy is displayed to the user (how that's displayed is a whole other complicated thing that I'm pretty sure doesn't factor in here).

`BackgroundWorker` was halfway working.  I set up the events and did the data acquisition in the `DoWork` handler and did the UI updating in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.  The function I'm performing repopulates the data hierarchy.

What I did first was have a button click handler collects parameters and passes them into the `DoWork` handler as arguments.  In the `DoWork` handler, primary data acquisition is performed and passed as an argument to the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.  There, the top-level custom class object is created, placed in the list, and populated with children.  Populating with children prepresents a secondary data acquisition operation (shorter than the first, but still a problem).  This locks up the UI only for the secondary operation, but that is still a problem

The second thing I tried was to move the object creation, secondary data collection, and child creation into the `DoWork` handler and just pass the top-level object out to the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler as an argument.  There, the only thing that would be done is to place the top-level object in the list.  However I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Is this application outside the scope of `BackgroundWorker`?  What can be used instead?  Is there a better way to structure my application that allows this hierarchy of objects to be created outside the UI thread at all?

EDIT (here's a simplified version of my code):
View (or my approximation of it)

```
private void PopulateTreeFromAssembly(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  //This is the button press code
        {
            //There is some UI stuff here that I stripped out
            if (BackgroundPopulateOperation.IsBusy != true)
            {
                BackgroundPopulateOperation.RunWorkerAsync(new PopulateOperationArgs(ViewMod.AssemblyNumber));
            }
        }

private void BackgroundPopulateOperation_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FileResult fileres = //Call file collection code that returns this custom object

            //Create a new Item object to act as the new root
            Item root = new Item(ViewMod, ViewMod.AssemblyNumber, 0, false);
            root.AttachedFile = fileres;
            root.SetIsChecked(true, true);
            root.IsAvailable = false;
            root.IsExpanded = true;
            root.UpdateFileSourceText();
            root.SetDescription(true, false);  //this is the secondary data acquisition
            root.PopulateChildren(false, true);    //this is also the secondary data acquisition (and creates child objects)

            //add the new root object to the argument object
            ((PopulateOperationArgs)e.Argument).NewRoot = root;

            //Send along the event argument object to the result so that it gets picked up by the RunWorkerCompleted event method
            e.Result = ((PopulateOperationArgs)e.Argument);
        }

        private void BackgroundPopulateOperation_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)  //Runs on the UI thread
        {
            //Update the UI elements after the new top-level file has been found
            ViewMod.TreeData.Clear();
            ViewMod.TreeData = new TreeGridModel();

            ViewMod.TreeData.Add(((PopulateOperationArgs)e.Result).NewRoot);  //<-------------Error here
            RootItem = ((PopulateOperationArgs)e.Result).NewRoot;  //update the reference variable to the top-level (root) tree item

            BOMTreeGrid.ItemsSource = ViewMod.TreeData.FlatModel;

            //There is some UI stuff here that I stripped out
        }
```

`TreeData` is an instance of a custom object that inherits `ObservableCollection`.  The data is represented using a "TreeGrid" control from [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1213466/WPF-TreeGrid-using-a-DataGrid) that I modified for my purposes.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of what you are trying to do? My C# is better than my English ;-)

Comment: Oh, and if you use MVVM properly, there's only a very select list of objects which can cause this exception. So, please also show if you have a MVVM structure with a datacontext etc.

Comment: I'll try to add a simplified version of the code I have to the original question.  Also, I tried my best to stick to the MVVM structure, but I'm very new to it so there's a good chance I screwed it up horribly.

Comment: No worries, it's fixable... and we can work on one thing at the time.  I wa wondering still; how much data is involved? How long does it take to fetch the data? And how many servers are there involved? And you well predefined is that data? If it are simple models, then we should be able to fix it rather quickly.

Comment: Your problem is at this line "*//There is some UI stuff here that I stripped out*". This is exactly what you should not do. Do not create UI elements in code behind, especially not in a background thread. Use DataTemplates to create them. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: @Stefan we're not talking about a lot of data here.  It's a file vault and it's only grabbing a couple of dozen files at a time.  It takes a minute or two to fetch the data.

Comment: @Clemens I am not creating UI elements in code behind.  Everything is done through XAML and data templates.  All I'm going in that commented area is changing properties (like IsEnabled, or Text) when you click the button.  I just deleted it to reduce clutter and improve readability in my example code.

Comment: Then I should slightly change my remark and say "Do not create or modify UI elements in code behind". UI element properties should be bound to view model property, but not be directly set.

Comment: @Clemens  Ah, okay.  My understanding was that the ViewModel should not be aware of the View.  In the case of disabling certain buttons when a different button is pressed, wouldn't having a ViewModel property like "bool ButtonXyzEnabled" violate that principle?  Like I said, I'm super new to MVVM so maybe I'm way off base here...

Comment: When there is a view model property that a property in the view is bound to, the view model does not know the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across multiple people saying that BackgroundWorker is older and that async and await should be used.

Well, [yes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html), but if you're new to C#, MVVM, **and** multithreading, feel free to take once concept at a time. There's "ideal" and there's also "good enough for a first solution". My blog posts and other writing usually take the "ideal" approach, but that's sometimes just not realistic.

The core principle is that UI elements may only be modified from their UI thread. This is called "thread affinity", and you can think of it as those elements *belonging* to a specific thread. So in your case, the tree view (and each tree view item) belong to the UI thread.

MVVM makes this a bit more complex because it defines objects (View Models) that are *connected* to UI elements. The rules here start to get a bit fuzzy - it's possible to do "simple" updates, and some "more complex" updates if you tweak some settings. But I prefer to treat View Model objects as also having thread affinity. In other words, all updates to View Models must be done on the UI thread. I find that making this (slightly over-strict) rule encourages cleaner code.

Now, to bring this down to multithreading, whether you use `Task.Run` or `BackgroundWorker`, this means your background work needs a way to send updates and/or results to the UI thread. I use the term "result" for the [final resulting value(s) of the background work that are returned only at the end](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-3.html), and "update" for any [intermediate value(s) that should update the UI immediately before the background work is done](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html).

In summary, what you need to do is:

1. Keep all your View Model types on the UI thread **only**. This includes all types implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` if those types are bound to UI elements.
2. Define *new* types that represent progress updates / results for your background work. These are "POCO" (Plain Old C# Objects). Have your background work report progress / return these types.
3. Write the code that copies the progress updates / results from the POCO types used by the background work into the View Model types. This code will run on the UI thread.

Comment: I just like to add that `Freezable` objects can be accessed on a different thread than the thread they are created on, when ` Freezable.Freeze()` was called (`IsFrozen` evaluates to `true`). Frozen objects are disconnected from the dispatcher system so that the thread-affinity is lifted: [Objects that derive from Freezable are free-threaded when they are frozen.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: I've done some more reading on the links provided in answers here, including a bunch of stuff from your blog (great stuff BTW, thanks for writing that).
I would like to avoid building bad habits and starting off on the wrong foot with BGW.  It looks like Task.Run is not right for my application because my operation is server-dependent and not CPU-bound.  Would that be correct?

Comment: I assume the API I'm using (Autodesk Vault) has "async" versions of the functions I'm using now that are blocking the UI thread.  I would just need to add an `async` to my method, change the return type to `Task<whatever>`, and then `await` each of the API calls that perform long-running operations (searches, downloads, and file opening in my case).  Does it sound like I'm on the right track here?

Comment: @OrionDeYoe: Yes, if your library's API has async functions, then that would be ideal. If it doesn't (not all libraries do), then using `Task.Run` is an acceptable workaround for a UI application.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I did some looking and it looks like the download function has an async version but none of the searching or file opening functions do.  I'll use the async version where I can and do `Task.Run` for the other ones then.

Comment: I stripped out the `BackgroundWorker` code and replaced it with the API async methods and the `Task.Run` code and everything looks like it's working.  Thank you so much for your help and clarification.